# Linux. Kerberos не находит сервер

Tags: linux, active-directory, opensuse, kerberos

Проблема в следующем: перевожу AD под Linux. Решил сервера делать на OpenSUSE, хотя это не принципиально. Есть железный сервер, на нем свежеустановленный OpenSUSE 42.1.

```
nt-50:~ # cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 172.16.0.3
nameserver 172.16.0.4
search npc-mka.local

nt-50:~ # cat /etc/krb5.conf 
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = NPC-MKA.LOCAL
    dns_lookup_realm = true
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
```

Сервер 4 это PDC под Windows Server 2012R2, сервер 3 это bdc под 2012R2.
Так вот kinit говорит что не может найти ни один сервер. Хотя ради интереса на моей ноуте под Ubuntu с этими же настройками все отлично работает.

Ради интереса поставил точно такой-же дистрибутив OpenSUSE в виртуальную машину, содержимое resolv и krb точно такое-же, и kinit отлично находит сервер и авторизуется на нем.

Если в krb5.conf дописать адреса сервера:

```
[realms]
    NPC-MKA.LOCAL = {
        kdc = 172.16.0.4
        default_domain = npc-mka.local
        admin_server = 172.16.0.4
    }
```

То kinit находит сервер и авторизуется без проблем.
Ну и пара служебных проверок на этом не работающем сервере:

```
nt-50:~ # host npc-mka.local
npc-mka.local has address 172.16.0.4
npc-mka.local has address 172.16.0.3
nt-50:~ # host npc.npc-mka.local
npc.npc-mka.local has address 172.16.0.3
nt-50:~ # host mka.npc-mka.local
mka.npc-mka.local has address 172.16.0.4
nt-50:~ # host 172.16.0.3
3.0.16.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer npc.npc-mka.local.
nt-50:~ # host 172.16.0.4
4.0.16.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer mka.npc-mka.local.
nt-50:~ # nslookup npc-mka.local
Server:     172.16.0.3
Address:    172.16.0.3#53

Name:   npc-mka.local
Address: 172.16.0.3
Name:   npc-mka.local
Address: 172.16.0.4
```

Уже всю голову сломал в чем может быть проблема, только что сетевой трафик пока не ловил, но чувствую скоро придется. Где может крыться проблема, скажите пожалуйста?

Comment: поверхностный взгляд на вопрос сразу наталкивается на название *tld*, которое [лучше не использовать](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local#Microsoft_recommendations): `local` (по крайней мере в приведённых в вопросе целях).

Comment: Ну сейчас уже его не поменять. Если придется домен подминать заного, переделаю. Только вот тут поднимается другой вопрос: если например использовать доменное имя такое-же, как имя нашего сайта, тогда есть небольшая проблема с доступностью сайта, либо всех надо перенаправлять на субдомен www, либо ставить кеширующий сервер, например nginx.

Comment: просто не используйте *tld* `local`, т.к. он использвуется *mdns* оно же *bonlour* оно же *zeroconf*. что угодно иное (не пересекающееся с зарегистрированными [tld](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видно проблема в том, что современные дистрибутивы криво отрабатывают .local
Наткнулся на такую статью: https://habrahabr.ru/post/103009/
Проблема решилась.